# "error: bad operand types for binary operator '&&' java issue

Tags: java

This has been driving me NUTS. I need to get this sorted by 2nd of Jan, and it decides to eat itself into a void of disrepair. Cursed code. Any help would be greatly appreciated (I've been using jdoodle to run the code).

The code is supposed to output zodiac stuff currently, and the sign section has been giving me the most jiff.

```
    if((month == 1) && (day <= 20) || (month == 12) && ((day >= 22))) {
    sign = "Capricorn";
    }
    if ((month == 1) || (month == 2) && (day <= 19)); {
    sign = "Aquarius";
    }
    if ((month == 2) || (month == 3) && (day <= 20)); {
    sign = "Pisces";
    }
    if ((month == 3) || (month == 4) && (day <= 19)); {
    sign = "Aries";
    }
    if ((month == 4) || (month == 5) && (day <= 21)); {
    sign = "Taurus";
    }
    if ((month == 5) || (month == 6) && (day <= 21)); {
    sign = "Gemini";
    }
    if ((month == 6) || (month == 7) && (day <= 23)); {
    sign = "Cancer";
    }
    if ((month == 7) || (month = 8) && (day <= 23)); {
    sign = "Leo";
    }
    if ((month == 8) || (month = 9) && (day <= 23)); {
    sign = "Virgo";
    }
    if ((month = 9) || (month = 10) && (day <= 23)); {
    sign = "Libra";
    }
    if ((month = 10) || (month = 11) && (day <= 22)); {
    sign = "Scorpio";
    }
    if (month == 12) {
    sign = "Sagittarius";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few issues:

1. You need to remove the ";" following each if statement as that essentially terminates the if-statement.
2. You will need to use "==" to compare integer values as opposed to "=" which you have used for some of the latter conditions.
3. You should use if-else you avoid checking once the sign has been found.
4. You have many redundant brackets. While this is not in itself an issue, it makes reading significantly more difficult.
5. While the logic you had was technically correct, note that the only reason why p || q && r <=> p || (q && r) is due to the [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) in Java. In this, && is applied before ||, hence you get the expected result. If this was not the case, you would apply || before &&, essentially having (p || q) && r, which is not logically equivalent to p || (q && r). Put simply; be careful with your logic.

Changing to this makes the code look more concise and produces expected results:

```
if((month == 1 && day <= 20) || (month == 12 && day >= 22)) sign = "Capricorn";
else if (month == 1 || (month == 2 && day <= 19)) sign = "Aquarius";
else if (month == 2 || (month == 3 && day <= 20)) sign = "Pisces";
else if (month == 3 || (month == 4 && day <= 19)) sign = "Aries";
else if (month == 4 || (month == 5 && day <= 21)) sign = "Taurus";
else if (month == 5 || (month == 6 && day <= 21)) sign = "Gemini";
else if (month == 6 || (month == 7 && day <= 23)) sign = "Cancer";
else if (month == 7 || (month == 8 && day <= 23)) sign = "Leo";
else if (month == 8 || (month == 9 && day <= 23)) sign = "Virgo";
else if (month == 9 || (month == 10 && day <= 23)) sign = "Libra";
else if (month == 10 || (month == 11 && day <= 22)) sign = "Scorpio";
else if (month == 12) sign = "Sagittarius";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((month == 1) && (day <= 20) || (month == 12) && ((day >= 22))) {
    sign = "Capricorn";
} else if ((month == 1) || (month == 2) && (day <= 19)) {
    sign = "Aquarius";
} else if ((month == 2) || (month == 3) && (day <= 20)) {
    sign = "Pisces";
} else if ((month == 3) || (month == 4) && (day <= 19)) {
    sign = "Aries";
} else if ((month == 4) || (month == 5) && (day <= 21)) {
    sign = "Taurus";
} else if ((month == 5) || (month == 6) && (day <= 21)) {
    sign = "Gemini";
} else if ((month == 6) || (month == 7) && (day <= 23)) {
    sign = "Cancer";
} else if ((month == 7) || (month == 8) && (day <= 23)) {
    sign = "Leo";
} else if ((month == 8) || (month == 9) && (day <= 23)) {
    sign = "Virgo";
} else if ((month == 9) || (month == 10) && (day <= 23)) {
    sign = "Libra";
} else if ((month == 10) || (month == 11) && (day <= 22)) {
    sign = "Scorpio";
} else if (month == 12) {
    sign = "Sagittarius";
}
```

1. remove the `;` from end of every `if`
2. add `else` before `if`
3. change `=` to `==`